# Django internal server error on json.dumps

Tags: json, django

I'm using ajax for a get request, the database is queried, then (should at least) return a json object. The problem is when I try to create the json object. I am getting an internal server error 500. Thank you for the help.

view:

```
def fabric(request, id):

      test = Topics.objects.get(topicId= id)
      ids = Topics.objects.get(topic= test)

      fabrics = [model_to_dict(fabric) for fabric in Fabrics.objects.filter(fabTopic_id=ids.id)]
      print fabrics                     #prints fabrics string 
      fabric_list = json.dumps(fabrics)
      print "test"                      #doesn't print

      return HttpResponse(fabric_list, content_type='application/json')
```

printed fabrics string:

```
[{'fabTopic': 1, 'isPremium': False, 'fabWeave': u'', 'fabImage_secondary': <ProcessedImageFieldFile: avatars/cotton2_1.jpg>, 'fabContent': u'', 'fabName': u'Cotton', 'fabImage': <ProcessedImageFieldFile: avatars/cotton1_1.jpg>, 'fabVideoURL': u'', 'fabDye': u'', 'fabFinish': u'', 'fabVideo': u'', 'fabDescription': u'Cotton is a cellulosic fiber obtained from the seed of a cotton plant Depending on the fiber length and/or finish, fabrics can h', u'id': 1}]
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFill

class Catagories(models.Model):
     catagory = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     categoryId = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.catagory 

class Topics(models.Model):
    fabCatagory = models.ForeignKey(Catagories)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    topicId = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.topic 

class Fabrics(models.Model):
    fabTopic = models.ForeignKey(Topics)
    fabName = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    fabContent = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    fabWeave = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    fabDye = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    fabFinish = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    fabDescription = models.CharField(max_length=8192) 
    fabImage = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='avatars',
                                       processors=[ResizeToFill(250, 185)],
                                       format='JPEG',
                                       options={'quality': 60},blank=True) 
    fabImage_secondary = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='avatars',
                                       processors=[ResizeToFill(500, 370)],
                                       format='JPEG',
                                       options={'quality': 60},blank=True)
    fabVideo = EmbedVideoField(blank=True)
    fabVideoURL = models.URLField(blank=True)
    isPremium = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.fabName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are naively trying to serialize a dict with unserializable items, such as `'fabImage_secondary': <ProcessedImageFieldFile: avatars/cotton2_1.jpg>`.

The very least, you want to use a proper serializer:

```
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize('json', Fabrics.objects.filter(fabTopic_id=ids.id), fields=('a', 'b'))
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/ for more details.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the problem. I really appreciate it. I understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Run your `json.dumps` in python script outside the django and see the error.

Or just turn on django logging to print errors on screen.

Probably json.dumps cannot serialize your Image object. By default json.dumps can serialize and deserialize only simple types like lists, dicts, numbers and strings.
You have to provide your image in some `simpler` form for serializer, as a path to the file (string) or array of byts (in python2 is also string).

Comment: This was helpful, helps with debugging.